# The proof of Lemma 10.1 in Nik’s book about forcing

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, forcing

I’m an undergraduate student trying to teach myself set-theory. And I have some trouble understanding the density of a constructed set.

In **Lemma 10.1** of [Nik’s book](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1295.03001), it states: *Let $G$ be a generic ideal of $P$, let $D \in \mathbf M$ be a subset of $P$, and suppose every element of $G$ is compatible with some element in $D$, then $G$ must intersect $D$.*

In Nik’s proof, he introduced the set $$D’=\{p\in P:p\supset q\ \ {\rm for\ some\ }q\ {\rm in\ }D\}\cup\{p\in P:p\ {\rm is\ incompatible\ with\ every\ }q\in D\}$$
and claims that the set $D’$ is dense in $P$, which I had trouble verifying.
The information I had seems so limited and I don’t know where to start with.
I had to show that for any $q\in P$, there’s some $p\in D’$ such that $p$ extends $q$. I tried to assume $q\in D$, then it seems natural to divide it in to two cases, where

1. There’s some $p\in D’$ such that $p$ extends $q$.
2. Any $p\in D’$, $p$ is not a extension of $q$.

And I have to show that case 2 will not hold. But I can’t see how this could be done neither.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Am I missing or misunderstanding some basic ideas about this subject?

Comment: What is the title of the book? What are $P$ and $\mathbf M$?

Comment: The title is _Forcing for Mathematicals_, **M** is an countable transitive model, and _P_ is a partial order that lies in **M**, and for any _p,q_ in _P_, _q_ extends _p_ iff p is a subset of q. It’s the first time that I ask a question, and I’m sorry that I left those information behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any condition in $p\in P$, either it is incompatible with the whole of $D$, in which case it is inside $D'$, or it is compatible with some $q\in D$, and therefore there is some $r$ which extends both $p$ and $q$, and therefore, by definition $r\in D'$.

So either $p$ was already in $D'$, or it has an extension in $D'$. In either case, $D'$ is dense. As a good exercise, try to prove that it is also open.